# How is a mean defined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, means

How exactly is a mean defined? There are obviously some similarities I can see between different types of means like the arithmetic and geometric means, but I would like to formalize the idea of a mean. So far, here is my progress:

Let $S=\{(x,n):n\in\mathbf N\}$ be nonempty. Essentially, $x$ represents a data point and $n$ represents the number of repetitions of that data point. Then we can represent the arithmetic mean as
$$A(S)=\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{(x,n)\in S}nx$$
and the geometric mean (assuming $x\geq0\,\forall (x,n)\in S$) as
$$G(S)=\bigg(\prod_{(x,n)\in S}x^n\bigg)^{1/|S|}.$$
It is easy to see that if $|S|=1$, i.e. $S$ contains only one data point regardless of repetition, that both means should equal the value of that data point. What other properties are needed to define a mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean

Comment: $min(S) \leq mean(S) \leq max(S)$ ?

Comment: See this page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency

Comment: Conceptually, a mean is some kind of "central point". Other than in some way satisfying that concept, it can be defined almost arbitrarily (just pick a new name so as not to confuse with standard means).

Comment: Maybe interesting to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Generalized_f-mean

Comment: Many averages can be defined, e.g. multiplicative, geometric, bigeometrc, angeometric, etc... i learned of a few when studying Non-Newtonian Calcili... https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Non_Newtonian_Calculus.html?id=RLuJmE5y8pYC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can observe, the geometric and harmonic and RMS means are equivalent to the arithmetic mean modulo a nonlinear, invertible transformation:

$$\log G(S)=A(\log S),$$

$$G(S)=e^{A(\log S)},$$
and
$$\frac1{H(S)}=A\left(\frac1S\right),$$
$$H(S)=\frac1{A\left(\dfrac1S\right)},$$

and

$$RMS^2(S)=A\left(S^2\right),$$
$$RMS(S)=\sqrt{A\left(S^2\right)}.$$

with a somewhat condensed notation.

---

An empirical mean is homogeneous (same dimension as the data), insensitive to a permutation, representative of a central trend and comprised between the extreme values.

---

We can invent the "exponential mean", such that

$$e^{E(S)}=A(e^S),$$

$$E(S)=\log A(e^S).$$

Comment: A nice answer!${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume the $x$ are samples from a probability distribution $p$. (Let $X\sim p$ be such a random variable.) For some function $m$ to be a *mean* we could define it using following properties:

In general you probably want $m$ to be a [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator) and [unbiased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator#Bias) estimator of the expected value $E[X]$.